# Apache Drill reading gz and snappy performance

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, parquet, apache-drill

I'm using Apache Drill 1.8. and for test porpoise I made from .csv two parquet files. CSV was about 4GB big, parquet with gz codec 120MB and second parquet with snappy codec about 250GB big.

As Spark is using snappy as default codec, and snappy should by performance be faster I face with one problem.

This are my files with block size and etc on Hadoop:

1. With snappy codec:
   [image]
2. With gz codec:
   [image]

Time when I'm trying to query in Drill (which have by default snappy codec) parquet files on snappy codec is around 18seconds.
Time when I'm trying to query in Drill parquet files on gz codec with the same query is around 8seconds.

(It's simple query with select 5 columns, ordering by one and limiting on one)

I'm little confused now. Isn't snappy more efficient with I/O? Am I making mistake somewhere or this is how it works.
If someone could explain me this I would be super grateful because I couln't find anything useful on net.
Thank you once more!

Comment: With the amount of data you are trying you shouldn't see any difference in performance. Check Query Profile page to see, which part it spend more time. Post query profiles, will try to answer more.

Answer (score 0):

In your original post you said the parquet with snappy file was 250 GB, did you mean 250 MB?

At least with HDFS, you want the parquet file size (row group) to be equal to the block size. You might have a problem because your block size is 128 MB and the file size is 250 MB.